# My function get_subtotal should be adding all product price, what I am doing wrong with the loop?

Tags: python, class, display

Function `get_subtotal` - Sums the price of each product and returns it
Function `get_tax` - Returns 6.5% times the subtotal
Function `get_total` - Returns the subtotal plus the tax
these are inside the Class.

```
class Order():
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = ""
        self.products = [] 

def get_subtotal(self):
    self.total = 0
    for item in self.products:
        self.total += 1
    return self.total

def get_tax(self):
    return self.total * 0.065

def get_total(self):
    return self.total + self.get_tax()`
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the identation in `get_subtotal` method, if you put the `return`stament  inside the `for` loop it will return only the first item!. But still not understanding, because your method only count the lenght of the products lists, maybe is some like this?

```
def get_subtotal(self):
    self.total = 0
    for item in self.products:
      self.total += item
    return self.total
```